# Input masking on caldera form

Tags: wordpress, postal-code, input-mask

I am using Caldera form plugin for WordPress.
[Caldera Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms)

I want to mask input for Germany postcode. for that, I need input that accept only 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `99999` to the 'Mask' Field. Make sure to tick the Masked Input checkbox